# SCSS not compiling '@use' statement

Tags: css, sass

I am using Gulp to compile scss to css. When I use a `@use` statement, it doesn't seem to compile the css correctly into my css file, just copies the `@use` statement over. What am I doing wrong?

SCSS:

```
@use 'icons';
@use 'fancy-hover';

body {
...
}

.some-class {
...
}
```

CSS:

```
@use 'icons'; // should output the compiled css from icons.scss
@use 'fancy-hover'; // should output the compiled css from fancy-hover.scss
body {...}
.some-class {...}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [At-rule @use in sass compiles incorrectly using gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62739242/at-rule-use-in-sass-compiles-incorrectly-using-gulp)

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: It specifically mentions that gulp doesn’t support @use currently in the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I'll take it into consideration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are using Node-Sass, `@use` is only supported by Dart-Sass (yet, and probably forever). You need to either use `@import` instead or import Dart-Sass.

Hope this was a some what satisfying answer ;D

Comment: Thank you, I chose `@use` because the documentation at sass-lang.com says `@import` is discouraged and being phased out. https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import

Comment: @noclist, yeah, that's probably from 3 years ago...